# Can resetProgress reset an entire form, including any existing tags?

Tags: forms, vue.js, nuxt.js, reset

This is a method for creating input tags that can be selectively deleted by the user. At present the Reset button clears the Input but leaves any tags that have already been created. How can the Reset button also delete any existing tags?

```
<template>
<div>
  <form>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="text" v-model.trim="tag" placeholder="Type here" @keypress.prevent.stop.enter="addTag">
      <button @click.prevent.stop="addTag">Add</button></div><br>

    <span class="tag" v-for="(tag, index) in tags" :key="index">
      <span>{{ tag }}</span><span class="delete" @click="tags.splice(index, 1)"> &times;</span></span>

    <div class="item">
      <button type="reset" on:click="resetProgress">Reset</button>
      <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button></div>
  </form>
</div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
      }
  },

  watch: {
    tags(n, o) {
      this.$emit('input', n);
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      tag: '',
      tags: this.value || [],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    addTag() {
      if (this.tag && ! this.tags.includes(this.tag)) {
        this.tags.push(this.tag);
        this.tag = '';
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You haven't defined a method named 'resetProgress'. Input is cleared only because that's default browser behavior for a button with `type='reset'`. You can test by replacing `resetProgress` with `tags = []`, or making a resetProgress method which does the same.

Also: it's `v-on:click` or `@click` for the vue directive, or `onclick` for the HTML event. Not `on:click` as you have in your code.

Comment: Many thanks for alerting me to that @Excalibaard, it makes me wonder how many more instances there are of browser finesse in my code!